# Load Site based item only in 'Multilist With Search'

Tags: content-search, sxa-search

I am working on `Sitecore 9.1` with `SXA` `multisite` application.

I have a folder in every site  e.g `Site-1/data/Tags/`

I created page items with a field `Multilist With Search` type

Now I want to load data in this field only with Tags data belonging to that site only.

I am trying to pass source in 'multilist with search' like **`StartSearchLocation=query:$site/Data/Tag Repository/*[@@templatename='Tag']&Filter=+_templatename:Tag`**

But it does not work.

If I pass query like **`StartSearchLocation={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}&Filter=_template:{68BA23FD-8270-4675-97EA-4FAFC7CF3AB9}`**

then 'Multilist with Search' field loads data from all the sites.

Please suggest me how can I make sure data loads only from that site where item is created.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think SXA provides this OOTB, we need to create QueryToken for `Multlist With Search`. The `Multilist with Search` field uses a `SourceFilterBuilder` class to parse its field source. Sitecore uses `SourceFilterBuilderFactory` to create the `SourceFilterBuilder`

You can follow this blog -

https://www.coreysmith.co/sxa-multilist-search-query-tokens/

Needs to extend `SourceFilterBuilderFactory` class -

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Buckets.FieldTypes;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Services;

namespace CoreySmith.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions
{
  public class QueryTokenSourceFilterBuilderFactory : SourceFilterBuilderFactory
  {
    private readonly IQueryService _queryService;

    public QueryTokenSourceFilterBuilderFactory(IQueryService queryService)
    {
      _queryService = queryService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queryService));
    }

    public override SourceFilterBuilder CreateSourceFilterBuilder(Item targetItem, string fieldId, string fieldSource)
    {
      if (targetItem == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(targetItem));
      if (fieldId == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fieldId));
      if (fieldSource == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fieldSource));

      var startSearchLocation = StringUtil.ExtractParameter("StartSearchLocation", fieldSource);
      if (!StartSearchLocationContainsQueryToken(startSearchLocation))
      {
        return base.CreateSourceFilterBuilder(targetItem, fieldId, fieldSource);
      }

      var resolvedStartSearchLocation = ResolveStartSearchLocation(startSearchLocation, targetItem);
      var resolvedFieldSource = fieldSource.Replace(startSearchLocation, resolvedStartSearchLocation);
      return base.CreateSourceFilterBuilder(targetItem, fieldId, resolvedFieldSource);
    }

    private static bool StartSearchLocationContainsQueryToken(string startSearchLocation)
    {
      return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(startSearchLocation)
           && startSearchLocation.StartsWith("query:")
           && startSearchLocation.Contains("$");
    }

    private string ResolveStartSearchLocation(string startSearchLocation, Item targetItem)
    {
      var query = ParseStartSearchLocationIntoQuery(startSearchLocation);
      var resolvedStartSearchLocation = _queryService.Resolve(query, targetItem.ID.ToString());

      // Multilist with Search fields only support one StartSearchLocation. If a pipe-delimited list
      // is set on the field source, no results will be returned; instead, return the first result.
      var firstStartSearchLocation = resolvedStartSearchLocation.Split('|').FirstOrDefault();
      return $"query:{firstStartSearchLocation}";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The StartSearchLocation parameter requires '->' in place of '=' within Sitecore queries.
    /// For example: StartSearchLocation=query:/sitecore/content//*[@@template->'SomeTemplate']
    /// The SXA query token resolver doesn't like '->', so replace with '=' for the Sitecore
    /// query engine.
    /// </summary>
    private static string ParseStartSearchLocationIntoQuery(string startSearchLocation)
    {
      return startSearchLocation.Replace("->", "=");
    }
  }
}
```

Then register the `QueryTokenSourceFilterBuilderFactory` with Sitecore's DI container. This will replace the `SourceFilterBuilderFactory` implementation that Sitecore uses out of the box.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore.Buckets.FieldTypes;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;

    namespace CoreySmith.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions
    {
      public class SitecoreExtensionsConfigurator : IServicesConfigurator
      {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
          serviceCollection.AddSingleton<SourceFilterBuilderFactory, QueryTokenSourceFilterBuilderFactory>();
        }
      }
    }
```

Patch the configurator in through config:

```
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <services>
      <configurator type="CoreySmith.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.SitecoreExtensionsConfigurator, CoreySmith.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions" />
    </services>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Then use it like below -

```
StartSearchLocation=query:$site/*[@@name='Data']/*[@@templatename='Video Folder']&TemplateFilter={ADE9EFF4-DA78-4E26-9248-B01BD93EAE95}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try.